# $W \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ and $Y = X$ if $W = 1$ and $-X$ otherwise where $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability

I have seen this $W \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ and $Y =  X$ if $W = 1$ and $-X$ otherwise where $X \sim N(0,1)$ example used in numerous occasions to show that $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and that $Y$ and $X$ are not independent, hence $X+Y$ is not necessarily normal.

It is intuitive to me $Y$ is distributed with $N(0,1)$ from a symmetry argument. But I am wondering how you actually go about proving $Y \sim N(0,1)$ mathematically?

I think I'm really just looking for a symbolical proof of this. We know that $Y= \pm X$ and $\pm X \sim N(0,1)$, so it's obvious $Y \sim N(0,1)$.
I think maybe I'm looking for how to show $f_Y = N(0,1)$?

Comment: $\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$It you want to show it mathematically, just show that $\P(Y\le x) = \P(X\le x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the law of total probability
$$
f_Y(y) = \sum_{w\in\{0,1\}}f_{Y|W}{(y|w)}P_W(w) = 0.5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}+0.5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}
$$

Comment: What if $X \sim N(c, 1)$ where $c \neq 0$? In this situation, the symmetry would break, and $Y$ would not be normally distributed?

Comment: Correct. In such a case you will have $$0.5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y-c)^2/2}+0.5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y+c)^2/2}$$ that is not normal

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of distribution? It's bimodal, I believe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution